# Import database dump file to excel

Tags: python, excel, jupyter-notebook, data-analysis, dump

I'm wondering if it is possible for a (database) dump file to be imported to excel. Eventually, I'll be analyzing the data with Python Jupyter Notebook. Also, can it also be imported onto Jupyter Notebook? How can I open the dump file with an excel to display the information of a table like below?

Below is an example lets say from Information Table

[image]

Comment: This question breaks almost every guideline for StackOverflow questions, asking if it's possible is not really helpful, as "yes" is probably not the answer you're looking for. And without any details about the database type, the format in which it dumps data, why you don't access the database directly, what you need to be able to do to the data - let alone some example or description of what you've tried already and what the problem is - it's impossible to provide a good answer.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding correctly, you can read in an xlsx file into your jupyter notebook and then slice and dice as you need. When you are finished, you can export it to a number of sources, including excel.

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/io.html

See the section focused on excel

the code is something like

```
read_excel
```

Comment: I know that. But there is a process of getting data from the dump file onto the excel file. I'm unsure if it is possible to extract the data.

Answer (score 0):

Databases typically store tables of data, as do Excel workbooks, so the answer is 'probably, yes'. And since you can read and process Excel sheets using Python, you can also use the data in Jupyter Notebook.

But without knowing anything about what's in your database, what kind of database it is, what you plan to do to the data in Excel (and why you don't just read the database from Jupyter), it's impossible to give a more complete answer.

Comment: I would like to see the data listed under (let'say Table A). So I expect the data to be listed onto my excel. How can I open a dump file with excel?

Comment: You're asking really general questions, without providing enough information to answer them. I don't know what kind of dump file you're talking about (it depends on the type of database and for many databases, there's multiple formats to dump to). Excel will be able to read some of them, but most will need processing - and even then, reading a dump may be a worse idea than just accessing the database directly from Excel. You're also not saying why you need it in Excel, so helping you find the right way to do it isn't possible. Please edit your question to be more clear.